# Sorting a lot of numbers in same script

Tags: jquery, sorting

I need help sorting some youtube videos by the viewcount, this is the script i use for embedding the youtube videos with visual view count and title on the website ( sorry if it is a bit messy):

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Qq7mpb-hCBY&key=[key]', function(data){
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=mxHB21dKmkw&key=[key]', function(data2){
        {$('body').append('<div class = videoframe><div class = video><iframe src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k width = 98.5% height = 140 allowfullscreen =allowfullscreen></iframe><div class = counter>'+data.items[0].statistics.viewCount +'</div><div class = title>'+ data2.items[0].snippet.title+'</div></div></div>');}
    });
});
</script>
```

Imagine there being 100+ youtube videos inside that script (which is placed in my body), i want a button that can, on press, sort the youtube videos by view count.

I am not very experienced with Jquery, which is why i ask for help on this awesome forum/help service. I understand a bit of the whole "sorting deal" with Jquery, but no enough to understand how to do it in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.sort()` function, but it's a javascript function that works with arrays, so you need to put all your elements in an array. For that, you can use the `.get()` jquery function, that gets a set of jquery objects and convert it to an array of DOM elements.

Putting all together...

```
$('button#views').click(function() {

    // Get all your videoframe divs and convert it in an array of DOM elements.
    var videos = $('div.videoframe').get();

    // Sort the array based in the value of the div.counter value (descendent).
    videos.sort(function(a,b) {
        return parseInt($(b).find('div.counter').text()) - parseInt($(a).find('div.counter').text());
    });

    // Replace current content with the new ordered set of elements.
    $('body').html($(videos));

});
```

And here you have a fiddle example... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/858u58a7/3/

***EDITED***:

Apparently, you want all your `div.videoframe` containers to be inside of a container `div`. The easiest approach would be create that empty container in the HTML code (positioning it where you want the content to be added) and then add the responses to that container instead of to `body` directly. If for some reason you can't modify the HTML, you can add that container with jQuery before the `getJSON` calls (here you have an example where you add it to the end od the `body` element)...

```
<script>
$('body').append('<div class="container"></div>');
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Qq7mpb-hCBY&key=[key]', function(data) {
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=mxHB21dKmkw&key=[key]', function(data2) {
        $('div.container').append('<div class = videoframe><div class = video><iframe src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k width = 98.5% height = 140 allowfullscreen =allowfullscreen></iframe><div class = counter>'+data.items[0].statistics.viewCount +'</div><div class = title>'+ data2.items[0].snippet.title+'</div></div></div>');
    });
});
</script>
```

... and the sorting code will change a little bit...

```
$('button#views').click(function() {

    // Get all your videoframe divs and convert it in an array of DOM elements.
    var videos = $('div.container div.videoframe').get();

    // Sort the array based in the value of the div.counter value (descendent).
    videos.sort(function(a,b) {
        return parseInt($(b).find('div.counter').text()) - parseInt($(a).find('div.counter').text());
    });

    // Replace current content with the new ordered set of elements.
    $('div.container').html($(videos));

});
```

Comment: Very helpful, definitely made me understand how it works.
Problem is;
As i said, my codes are messy, i can't get them setup in on big div, every video there is added is in their seperate div, which is really a problem at the moment, still trying to figure it out.
If only i could put all of them in one div, then i would be able to use your example.

Comment: I took a screenshot so u can see what i mean:
https://gyazo.com/d573b29d931897404c57177bdacf7851

Comment: You don't need just one `div`. My solution is for your case, having one div for each video.  Have you check the fiddle? The HTML is based in the code you show in your question (one `div.videoframe` for each video)

Comment: Yeah ok, it kinda works, problem is, when i press one of the buttons, it will sort, but it also duplicates the amount of videos added by x amount, so for et cetera if there is 4, it will add like another 16, and so on till browser crash. See it here:
https://gyazo.com/b1d2dc0a59dd69fd27d8a6b8be7b7bf0

And here a fiddle so you can see exactly how the codes look:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/dq7thh4b/1/

Comment: ahh wait, i edited my code from the other day, let me just do a recheck, sorry.
EDIT: Still duplicates the videos

Comment: Messing about, i figured it out. You are godsent, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Good to hear!! Have a nice day and happy coding!

Comment: Now that we are at it, and i would private message you but can't: This code you gave me practially puts it all in one single div after the buttons are pressed, but that is something i want it to be already when u load the page, how would u do that? I can only make it work when u click on the button, "$(document).ready(myfunction)" does not work. Theoretically, it's your code, but without (or with, still doesn't work) the sorting bit.

Comment: To be able to sort with my solution you need at least one container `div` for each `iframe+div.counter+div.title` group. But, if what you want is having all that containers inside of one single container `div`, you can do changing the code you put in your question. I've edited my answer.